# word meaning ugly food that tastes good

Tags: single-word-requests

I use to listen to a radio show that taught you a new word daily. I always listed as I drove to school to teach. I wasn't able to write it down and have searched for that word again for yeas as this is how my cooking is hehe Ugly but tasty food.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, @Edwin Ashworth.

Comment: I'm not sure English would have a ***noun*** for food that's good to actually ***eat***, but ***unappetising*** in some other way (visually unattractive, nasty smell, dubious provenance,...). But one often-used term here is the [***yuck factor***.](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-food-mealworm-europe-idUSKBN29I145)

Comment: Personally I'd go with 'surprising' or 'deceptive' along with a description of the food, but that isn't really an answer. If the context is sufficiently modern/slangy, then maybe fug-licious to be fun. Dichotomous? You'd have to specify it was ugly and delicious. Results oriented? None of them really are an answer, but it depends on what you're looking for.

Comment: Food for the blind...